# jQuery bind events to dynamic events in a loop

Tags: jquery

I generate some elements in a loop and attach them to a div.

```
for (property in selectedGroup.properties) {
$d("<tr></tr>").html("<label for='" + property + "_input'>" + property + "</label><input     
id='" + property + "_input' type='text' value='" + selectedGroup.properties[property] +   
"'><input type='button' id='" + property + "_button' value='Save'/>").appendTo($d("  
[id$='data-menu']"));
....
```

After that I want to bind a event to every of this elements (input fields and buttons, here as an example a keyup event for the input field):

```
$d("#" + property).keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $d("#" + property).click();

            } else {
                $d("#" + property).css('background-color', '#FF6A6A');
            }
        });
```

This happens all in the loop. After that, all elements are created and are visible but only the last created element in the loop has the right eventhandler. All other elements have event handlers which trigger events for the last element. Why?

These are the two bindings, first one for the input field, second one for the button:

```
$d("#" + property + "_input").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $d("#" + property + "_button").click();

        } else {
            $d("#" + property + "_input").css('background-color', '#FF6A6A');
        }
    });

    $("#" + property + "_button").click(function(event) {

        selectedGroup.properties[property] = $d("#" + property + "_input").val();
        $d("#" + property + "_input").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        $d("#" + property + "_input").blur();
    });
```

Thank you very much.............but i have another problem now :-(.... Inside the click function I set the property to the value of the input field. Every step in the loop the property is different of course. In the fiddle the first is type, then name and then label. But when i do "selectedGroup.properties[property] = $d(this).siblings('input:first').val();" it always sets the label, that means property is always interpreted as "label"......

Comment: The last created property element in the loop has the right bindings, but all other are bound to the last one???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would rather suggest you to also add class to elements where you have added variable id `property`.say add class property using `class='property'`

```
for (property in selectedGroup.properties) {
$d("<tr></tr>").html("<label for='" + property + "_input'>" + property + "</label><input class='property' id='" + property + "_input' type='text' value='" + selectedGroup.properties[property] +  "'><input class='property' type='button' id='" + property + "_button' value='Save'/>").appendTo($d("[id$='data-menu']"));
```

also you can use `.on` along with `keyup` to set the keyup event. this way you will not need to bind `keyup` every time you change the DOM:

```
 $d(document).on('keyup','.property[type="text"]',function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $d(this).click();

    } else {
        $d(this).css('background-color', '#FF6A6A');
    }
});

$d(document).on('click', '.property[type="button"]', function(event) {
        properties[$d(this).attr('id').replace("_button","")]=$d(this).siblings('input:first').val();
        $d(this).siblings('input:first').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
         $d(this).siblings('input:first').blur();
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsF58/27/)**

Comment: But every property element has its input field and its button. So if i click the button it has to change the color of the corresponding input field. If all of these have the same class how do I distinguish the elements?

Comment: @user2934052:Updated the answer.

Comment: Thx so far, the first one for the input works, the second one doesn't. It doesn't change the color of the corresponding input nor sets the "selectedGroup.properties[property]" with the value of the input field.

Comment: @user2934052:can you create the fiddle. or share the error that you are getting.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, now it works to show you the problem [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcclane/dsF58/)

Comment: Thank you very much !!! But I have another question ( I updated my question above).

Comment: That does the trick!! Thanks a million!!!! By the way, do you have a short explanation why I can't use "property" as the actual element inside the loop?

Comment: Because property value does not exist when event is getting fired.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that after loop completed like;

```
for (property in selectedGroup.properties) {
$d("<tr></tr>").html("<label for='" + property + "_input'>" + property + "</label><input     
id='" + property + "_input' type='text' value='" + selectedGroup.properties[property] +   
"'><input type='button' id='" + property + "_button' value='Save'/>").appendTo($d("  
[id$='data-menu']"));
....




$d(".property").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $d(this).click();

    } else {
        $d(this).css('background-color', '#FF6A6A');
    }
});
```

Here is a working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/WJS7C/1/**